# How does the JVM know how much to read in the start address when reading object data?

Tags: java, jvm

I studied the following.
Object header consists of a mark word and a klass pointer.
In the case of an **array**, it additionally has **size header**.

In other words, there is no size information in the header of object data. So, how does the JVM know how far to read from the start address when reading object data?

Comment: Why do you think the *size* of the object is needed to read object's data? To read object data, you just need to know where that data is...

Comment: I think it need to do bound check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between an array and a "normal" object is that arrays can have different sizes, while every object of a given class has the same size. In a way, the size of non-array objects *is* stored, but not with every object, but only once in the respective class data (hence the class pointer).

Regarding accessing the data in an array/object, there is another difference: When accessing the element of an array, the JVM has to do a bounds check, which requires knowing the size of the array. When accessing the field of a normal object, however, this is not the case, as the number/positions of all fields is fixed (and known at class loading time) for every object of a given class. So usually, knowing the size of an object is not actually required to access its data. However, I want to relativize Sweeper's comment: The JVM *does* need to know the size of non-array objects, e.g., when moving them around as part of garbage collection compaction.

Comment: Is my understanding correct?
For arrays, access data by index.
A bound check is necessary because the value of the index may be invalid.
However, in the case of objects, data is accessed by field name.
So it doesn't need to do bounds checking, and it doesn't need to know the size.

Then, is it to access the memory address of the object through calculating the start address + the byte size of each field?

Comment: @korjun1993 Sound about right, yes. Start address + header size + size of preceding fields.

Comment: For completion: the validity of a field access is checked too. But a field access will always refer to the same field (unlike a potentially changing array index) and the fields declared by a class also never change (in one runtime), so this check is performed only once, by the verifier, before the code is executed the first time. Once it has been proven valid, it will always be valid (aside from potentially accessing `null`) and does not need to be checked again.

Comment: @Holger, yeah, cleared that up in the answer.